# Not able to install psycopg2 module when deploying Django to Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having trouble adding the psycopg2 module to my elastic beanstalk setup, so that I can deploy my Django project.

Some details:
Platform: Amazon Linux 2/3.3.14
Python 3.8 running on 64bit

Stack Trace from /var/log/web.stdout.log

```
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: [2022-06-22 02:39:11 +0000] [3578] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3578)
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: [2022-06-22 02:39:11 +0000] [3572] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: [2022-06-22 02:39:11 +0000] [3572] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: [2022-06-22 02:39:11 +0000] [3586] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: [2022-06-22 02:39:11 +0000] [3586] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (3586)
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: [2022-06-22 02:39:11 +0000] [3586] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
Jun 22 02:39:11 ip-172-31-20-172 web: [2022-06-22 02:39:11 +0000] [3592] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3592
Jun 22 02:39:12 ip-172-31-20-172 web: [2022-06-22 02:39:12 +0000] [3592] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Jun 22 02:39:12 ip-172-31-20-172 web: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 22 02:39:12 ip-172-31-20-172 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
Jun 22 02:39:12 ip-172-31-20-172 web: import psycopg2 as Database
Jun 22 02:39:12 ip-172-31-20-172 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
Jun 22 02:39:12 ip-172-31-20-172 web: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Jun 22 02:39:12 ip-172-31-20-172 web: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 22 02:39:12 ip-172-31-20-172 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
Jun 22 02:39:12 ip-172-31-20-172 web: worker.init_process()
```

.ebextensions > 01_packages.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql-devel: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
    amazon-linux-extras: []

commands:
    01_postgres_activate:
        command: sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql14
    02_postgres_install:ßßß
        command: sudo yum install -y postgresql-devel
```

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.5.2
certifi==2022.5.18.1
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
cryptography==37.0.2
defusedxml==0.7.1
Django==4.0.5
django-allauth==0.43.0
django-cors-headers==3.12.0
django-crispy-forms==1.10.0
django-debug-toolbar==3.2
django-quill-editor==0.1.40
djangorestframework==3.13.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
oauthlib==3.2.0
Pillow==9.1.1
psycopg2==2.9.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.4.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2022.1
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.9
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

Comment: can you try installing binary prior to running installing all libraries. 
**sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2**

Comment: @AbhishekJadav Amazon linux does not have `apt`.

Comment: What `:ßßß` is supposed to do?

Comment: we can try installing separately by `pip install psycopg2-binary` inside virtual environment

Comment: @Marcin, `:ßßß` was a typo. Thank you for catching that! I removed it. I have complications with cat-on-keyboard often.

Comment: @AbhishekJadav, I went into my ec2 instance and manually ran `pip install psycopg2-binary`, but I continue to receive the same error. 

Before all of that, I have continued to make sure to add all of my files to my local git, because elastic beanstalk uses those for deployment.